# How are storage costs computed for RMUs and FIUS?

Tags: untagged

In Business Strategy, at the beginning of each month, each player must pay storage costs for their RMUs and FIUs.

For RMUs, the costs written on the player board are the following :

> «... storing 7 or less costs $300 per unit, storing 8 or more costs
> $200 per unit.»

How should this rule be interpreted?

$300 per unit for the first 7 units and $200 for each unit over 7 ? $2300 for 8 units

OR

$200 per unit for all of the units, if the number of units is over 7 ? $1600 for 8 units

[Avalon-Hill's 1973 game Business Strategy](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1721/business-strategy)
[image: Board Game Geek image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be read as each unit costs that much. Something else to note is that once you hit 8 units you will actual pay less than you would for 7 units until you get up to 11 where it costs more than 7 units but is still cheaper per unit.

- 1 unit: $300 - $300 per unit
- 2 units: $600
- 3 units: $900
- 4 units: $1200
- 5 units: $1500
- 6 units: $1800
- 7 units: $2100
- 8 units: $1600 - $200 per unit
- 9 units: $1800
- 10 units: $2000
- 11 units: $2200